# How To Convert a Bi-Directional Link With MapStrcut

Tags: java, mapstruct

Here below is a very simplified car sharing model, where a `Car` might be used by more than one `User`. I need to convert a service object into a DTO object and vice-versa:

```
@Data
public class Car {

    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private List<CarUser> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public void linkUser(CarUser user) {
        this.users.add(user);
        user.setCar(this);
    }
}

@Data
public class CarUser {

    private String name;
    private Car car;
}

@Data
public class CarDTO {

    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private List<CarUserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public void linkUser(CarUserDTO user) {
        this.users.add(user);
        user.setCar(this);
    }
}

@Data
public class CarUserDTO {

    private String name;
    private CarDTO car;
}

@Mapper
public interface UserConverter {

    CarUser convert(final CarUserDTO user);
    CarUserDTO convert(final CarUser user);
}


@Mapper(uses = UserConverter.class)
public interface CarConverter {

    Car convert(final CarDTO car);
    CarDTO convert(final Car car);
}
```

Method `linkUser` creates a bi-directional link, i.e. it associates a given `User` to the current `Car` and the current `Car` to the given `User`. The problem with the `Mapper` in the code snippet above, is that the `car` attribute in classes `User`/`UserDTO` gets never set because of course the converter doesn't invoke `linkUser`. Is there any way to set that attribute? The tricky part here is that the `Car` to be set is actually the instance being converted. Any help would be really appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply define an [`@AfterMapping`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/AfterMapping.html) method in the `CarConverter`. The point is to clone the list of converted users and to set the `users` attribute to an empty list because the list of users will be refilled upon invoking the `linkUser` method.

```java
@Mapper(uses = UserConverter.class)
public interface CarConverter {

  Car convert(final CarDTO car);
  CarDTO convert(final Car car);

  @AfterMapping
  default void linkUsersDTO(Car source, @MappingTarget CarDTO target) {
    List<CarUserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>(target.getUsers());
    target.setUsers(new ArrayList<>());
    users.forEach(target::linkUser);
  }

  @AfterMapping
  default void linkUsers(CarDTO source, @MappingTarget Car target) {
    List<CarUser> users = new ArrayList<>(target.getUsers());
    target.setUsers(new ArrayList<>());
    users.forEach(target::linkUser);
  }

}
```

Additionally, since the user's `car` property is being set in the `@AfterMapping` method, it is unnecessary to map it in the `UserConverter::convert`.

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserConverter {

  @Mapping(target= "car",ignore = true)
  CarUser convert(final CarUserDTO user);

  @Mapping(target= "car",ignore = true)
  CarUserDTO convert(final CarUser user);

}
```

If not ignored, the `StackOverflowError` exception is thrown because the generated methods of `UserConverter` form a circular dependency.